# Formula Help IF/AND/OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an excel formula that tells me if I have completed the monthly check of if an employee has completed the submission of a survey. In Column G2 I have it tell me "N/A" if they have not submitted a survey and 0 if they have submitted a survey. In column L2 it tells me if the employee is "Terminated" or "Active". I'm trying to write a code that returns either "YES" or "NO" based on if G2="N/A" and L2= "Terminated" OR G2=0. If either the IF/AND function or the OR function is True, It would return the words "YES" meaning the employee has been accounted for in terms of their monthly survey.

The formula I have currently is =IF(AND(OR(G2="N/A",L2="Terminated",G2=0)),"YES","NO")

However, it does not satisfy what I am trying to have it do. If someone could help we write the IF AND OR formula I am trying to write that would be great.

Thank you for anyone that helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(G2="N/A",L2="Terminated"),G2=0),"YES","NO")
```

The AND should be in the OR.  IF `G2="N/A"` AND `L2="Terminated"` return `YES` OR IF `G2=0` return `YES`.  Otherwise return `NO`.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for pointing out what I was missing. I appreciate it!